# Has anyone got NVelocity working with ASP.NET MVC Preview 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nvelocity

I'm guessing I need to implement an `NVelocityViewEngine` and `NVelocityView` - but before I do I wanted to check to see if anyone has already done this.

I can't see anything in the [trunk](http://mvccontrib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) for [MVCContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib).

I've already seen the post below - I'm looking specifically for something which works with Preview 5:

- [Testing ScottGu: Alternate View Engines with ASP.NET MVC (NVelocity)](http://www.chadmyers.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/28/testing-scottgu-alternate-view-engines-with-asp.net-mvc-nvelocity.aspx)

Otherwise I'll start writing one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an NVelocity implementation in [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.org). You need to reference the MvcContrib.Castle dll.

Comment: Ahhh - so there is - it's called NVelocityViewFactory rather than NVelocityViewEngine - my oversight.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes, that's a naming convention left over from Preview 2. I think I'll rename it at some point before the next MVC release.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't have a clue about NVelocity, but [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/07/14/asp-net-mvc-tip-19-use-the-nvelocity-view-engine.aspx) is a link that might help you.

Comment: Sadly that's for Preview 4 I think.  There were some breaking changes in Preview 5.  Thanks anyway.